# Eclipse fails to build maven multi-module project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build a multi-module maven project in Eclipse, however, I get 8670 `Java Problems` in Eclipse Oxygen. My project has one parent project with its `pom.xml` that has the following secion declaring sub-modules:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>graph-algorithms-parent</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Neo4j Graph Algorithms</name>
<description>Efficient Graph Algorithms for Neo4j</description>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Benchmark</id>
        <modules>
            <module>benchmark</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>algo</module>
    <module>tests</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <neo4j.version>3.3.1</neo4j.version>
    <jmh.version>1.19</jmh.version>
    <javac.target>1.8</javac.target>
</properties>

<organization>
    <name>Neo4j, Inc.</name>
    <url>https://neo4j.com</url>
</organization>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>neo-technology</id>
        <organization>Neo4j, Inc.</organization>
        <url>https://neo4j.com</url>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>avgl</id>
        <organization>Avantgarde Labs GmbH</organization>
        <url>https://avantgarde-labs.de</url>
    </developer>
</developers>

<url>https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms</url>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms</url>
</scm>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3, 29 June 2007</name>
        <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt</url>
        <comments>
            Note that this license is for the project itself, and not for its dependencies.
            See the included NOTICE.txt file for further details.
        </comments>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>


<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.biville.florent</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-sproc-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Benchmark Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Neo4j Procedures require Java 8 -->
                <compilerVersion>${javac.target}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${javac.target}</source>
                <target>${javac.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
           <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.3</version>
           <inherited>false</inherited>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>generate-docs</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <backend>html5</backend>
               <!--preserveDirectories>true</preserveDirectories -->
               <imagesDir>images</imagesDir>
               <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/doc</sourceDirectory>
               <sourceDocumentName>index.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
               <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/docs</outputDirectory>
               <attributes>
                   <neo4j-version>${project.version}</neo4j-version>
               </attributes>
               <requires>
                   <require>asciidoctor-diagram</require>
               </requires>
               <source-highlighter>coderay</source-highlighter>
               <coderay-css>style</coderay-css>
           </configuration>
           <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
               <artifactId>asciidoctorj-diagram</artifactId>
               <version>1.3.1</version>
           </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.b1</version>
            <configuration>
                <header>gplv3-header.txt</header>
                <strictCheck>true</strictCheck>
                <failIfMissing>true</failIfMissing>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I have the 4 sub-modules `benchmark`, `core`, `algo`, `tests` with their own `pom.xml` all referencing the parent project correctly (with the correct version number). The actual project is from `neo4j` which you can find [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms).

I tried doing a `maven clean install` and the project builds successfully without any issues. However, when I import the projects to Eclipse, I get many errors (mostly from the parent project) that states either `... cannot be resolved to a type` or `... cannot be resolved`.

I tried doing a `Maven` -> `Update Project` without any success. I'm in the Project Explorer view in Eclipse with all 5 projects at the same level.

I also tried adding a `Active Maven Profiles` in Eclipse, however, did not resolve the issue. My Embedded Maven version is 3.3.9/1.8.2.20171007-0216

Comment: To be honest there no enough information to solve the issue, but I'd double check that eclipse is using the right version of maven and the right repo and I would ask to synchronize. If it fail I would remove all projects from eclipse and reimport.

Comment: @NicolasBousquet I added the full pom.xml from the parent project. My embedded maven installation version is 3.3.9. How do I ask to synchronize?

Comment: Is the parent project a Java project? If yes, this might be the issue.

Comment: Go to Preference, Maven double check the installation and repo you use in eclipse is the same as in command line (you can by the way re-index your m2 repo). Then delete all your projects if you have any, reimport them from existing maven projects, select only the child projects, wait for eclipse to finish. In desperate cases, start from a freshly created wrokspace. Also be sure of course your JRE/JVM setting in eclipse match that of maven.

Comment: @howlger yes, the parent project is a Java project.

Comment: @swdon Does deleting the parent project without its content fix your issue (assuming all Java code is in Java subprojects)?

Comment: I imported just the core and algo and tests projects. Then I deleted all 3 from workspace. And the imported all the projects (including the parent) to workspace. Also, my project was in a subfolder in work space. I moved the projects outside of this subdirectory. I think this was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Problem was, my Eclipse workspace was the directory called `workspace`. However, my maven projects were in a subfolder I created called `my_project`. When I cloned the repo, I `cd` into `my_project` and did `git clone`.

So, instead of choosing the highest level `workspace` folder as my Eclipse workspace, I chose the `/workspace/my_project` as workspace and the issue resolved.

Comment: You see the problem is that for this kind of stuff, a key missing information was not provided so it was hard to guess what was wrong ;)